# How do I extend the scrollview top under a navigation bar in iOS 12?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios12, uiedgeinsets

I have a `UIScrollView` under a *navigationbar* in a detail *viewcontroller*.

The *viewcontroller* settings are the following:

[image]

The *scrollview* is pinned to the `Safe Area` (`trailing`, `leading`, `bottom`, `top` = `0`).

[image]

I want to put the entire *scrollview* below/under the *navigationbar*, so that, if I make the *navigationbar* transparent, I can see the scrollview *pinned* to the top border of the device (while, at the moment, the scrollview area **top** corresponds to the **bottom** border of the navigationbar). The *navigationbar* should cover part of my *scrollview*.

I tried `adautomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`, and other similar solutions but nothing seemed to work.

Finally, I noticed if I replace the *safe area* top `constraint` with a superview `constraint` I get the expected result but I’m here to ask: is this the way to go? Is it safe? Are there any possibile drawbacks?

Comment: just pin with super view and set content inset in `viewDidLayout`

Comment: If your app looks okay on iPhoneX and higher, then nothing else to worry about. Safe area is there to help us pin views to the recommended margins, nothing else would break if you pin your view to the superview.